# Where can I find this Morse Theory result?

Tags: reference-request, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, morse-theory

I'm reading through chapter 1 of [Curve and Surface Reconstruction: Algorithm and Mathematical Analysis](https://books.google.it/books/about/Curve_and_Surface_Reconstruction.html?id=v_OyHkgVnnUC&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&redir_esc=y). There's **lemma 1.1** where in the proof apparently a result of Morse Theory is used, and I'd like to study the related theory so I can understand the result.

I quote only the relevant bit:

> We claim the function $h$ has a critical point in $Int (B \cap \Sigma)$ other than $m$ where $B$ becomes tangent to $\Sigma$. If not, as we shrink $B$ centrally the level set $bd (B \cap \Sigma)$ does not change topology until it reaches the minimum $m$ when it vanishes. This follows from Morse theory of smooth functions over smooth manifolds.

This relation between minimum and change of topology is exactly what I'm looking for.

Is there a specific theorem I can study to understand rigorously that statememt?

The only reference mentioned in the book is : Milnor (1963) Morse Theory.

I started reading through it but I couldn't find the specific result.

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 3):

This follows from (the proof of) Theorem 3.1 in Milnor's *Morse Theory*, which I paraphrase part of below.

> Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and let $f:M\to\mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function.  Let $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ with $a<b$ such that $f^{-1}([a,b])$ is compact and contains no critical points of $f$.  Then there is a diffeomorphism $f^{-1}((-\infty,a])\to f^{-1}((-\infty,b])$ which restricts to a diffeomorphism $f^{-1}(\{a\})\to f^{-1}(\{b\})$ [this latter part is not stated explicitly by Milnor but is clear from his proof].

In other words, the level sets of a smooth function on a compact manifold do not change topology unless you pass through a critical point.

Comment: What exactly is meant with "change of topology" in this context though?

Comment: It just means not being diffeomorphic.

Comment: My inner pedant remarks that "change of topology" would rather mean "not being homeomorphic". But, of course, being diffeomorphic implies being homeomorphic.

Comment: Not being homeomorphic/diffeomorphic to what? That's the bit I currently struggle with.

Comment: To each other, I take it. @user8469759

Comment: If $f^{-1}(\{b\})$ were not diffeomorphic to $f^{-1}(\{a\})$, you could say that the topology of the level sets changed between $a$ and $b$.